# Augmented Dicket Fuller test

Tags: stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

My assignment requires working on micro fit,  when conducting an ADF test without trend nor constant I got a positive t-ratio, how do i compare it to the t-stat? Does it have to be less or greater than the negative t-stat value?